# Is it possible to process video frames while the video file is still being written?

Tags: android, video-processing, android-mediarecorder

The goal is:
In Android, I take a video, and process each video frame, and record processed video frame into the output video file.

Of course, it would be perfect if it can be implemented real-time. However, the video recording fps is 15, and the average process time per frame is about 1/10 secs, ie, 10 frames/sec.  So I cannot do it in an real-time way. (BTW, even if the frame processing speed is about 1/15sec, there is no good way to get the frame data from the camera in an efficient way. PreviewPicture obviously is updated slower than the real fps)

So I plan to start another thread, while the video is recording to a video file, say, called videoFileBefore.mp4. Apparently, videoFileBefore.mp4 is in the recoding mode. But I want to open the file, process the available frames, and write them into another new video file, say called videoFileAfter.mp4.
If the video recording is 10 secs, then the app needs an extra 5 secs to finish the video processing. The whole process is 15 secs. (Here assumes the video recording takes little time. Being more accurately, we can add it in)

The second option is: I wait to process the video file, videoFileBefore.mp4, till the recording is finished, the whole time is:
10 secs + 15 secs = 25 secs.
So I prefer the first option: process a video file while it is being written.

But it seems the existing video formats do not support such operation.
Any idea?

Comment: Problem with your write than, read to write solution is about mp4 encoding/decoding time, this part is going to kill you. Do you have recording time? I mean if you have some fixed limit, you can easily calculate your buffer needed to store images in buffer first, than save them to a file after processing.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the recording time is random. It may be very long, like 1 hour. I am planning to improve the frame processing speed. If I can get the frame processing speed to 15-20 frames per second, how can I use the streaming output data from MediaRecorder directly? I do not want to use PreviewPicture data, which are very slow.